# Why does the guard not check the pastries?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-grand-budapest-hotel

In *The Grand Budapest Hotel*, Zero and Agatha smuggle tools into the prison by hiding them in pastries. Then there's a scene where a guard cuts up incoming packages - presumably to check for hidden contraband - but when the guard sees the pastries he doesn't cut them up despite them being very suspiciously shaped. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a comedy.

The cakes were blatantly shaped as escape tools, but due to the guards respect of M. Gustave and the high quality of'Mendel's' cakes he so often received, the guards stupidly decide not to cut into them so as not to spoil the presentation, despite the fact that they clearly contain contraband.